# Difference in the function (Game Theory)

Tags: notation, game-theory

I was hoping to know the difference between equation (1) and equation (2). Would they be considered equal or is equation (2) less strict compared with equation (1)?

Let the correspondence $F:\mathcal A→2^\mathcal A$ be defined as follows:

$F(\mathbf a)=f_1(\mathbf a_{-1})\times...\times f_ \mathcal K(\mathbf a_{-\mathcal K})$.

$\exists\mathbf a\in A: \mathbf a\in F(\mathbf a)$  (1)

$\forall k \in \mathcal K, \exists \mathbf a \in \mathcal A: a_k \in f_k(\mathbf a_{-k})$ (2)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement is less restrictive.

The first statement says that there exists some $\mathbf a\in A$ such that $a_1\in f_1(\mathbf a_{-1})$ $\ldots$ $a_\mathcal K\in f_{\mathcal K}(\mathbf a_{-\mathcal{K}})$.

The second statement says that for each $k\in\mathcal K$ there exists some $\mathbf a\in A$ (**and it is possible that this $\mathbf a$ is different for each $k\in\mathcal K$**) such that $a_k\in f_k(\mathbf a_{-k})$.

It may be more illuminating to write (2) as follows:
$$\forall k \in \mathcal K, \exists \mathbf a^k \in \mathcal A: a_k^k \in f_k(\mathbf a_{-k}^k)$$
to emphasize with a superscript that $\mathbf a$ need not be common across $(1,\ldots,\mathcal K)$, unlike in (1).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome.